# Appending a text with an appended dictionary python

Tags: python, string, list, file, dictionary

The issue is I want to add a student to an existing record then save it to a txt.file by using the file in python, However it wont append to the textfile. The expected outcome of my code is to add TWO students to the dictionary then save it to a text file then once that text file is read, the added students will appear.

```
while True:
def Menu(): #Menu Function

    print("****Student Record****")
    print()
    print("[1] Add Student")
    print("[2] View Student")
    print("[3] View all Students")
    print("[4] Delete a Student")
    print("[5] Delete all Students")
    print("[6] Load file")
    print("[7] Save to file")
    print("[0] Exit")

def save(): #isang student lang na-aadd
    saveHandle = open("record.txt", "a")
    for k in record: #Checks each key in dictionary
        student = k #each student is assigned to the key
        i = 0
        if student == str(k): #checks if student is in dictionary
            saveHandle.write(str(new + ",") 
            for k in record[k]:
                if i == 0:
                    saveHandle.write(str(k))
                if i == 1:
                    saveHandle.write(str(k))
                if i == 2:
                    saveHandle.write(str(k))
                if i == 3:
                    saveHandle.write(str(k))
                i = i + 1
def load():
    record = [] #oks na

    readHandle = open("record.txt", "r")

    for line in readHandle:
        student = line[:-1]
        record.append(student)

    readHandle.close()

    print(record)




Menu()


print() #space

option = int(input("Enter option: "))

print()

    record = {"2018-00000" : ["Jake Peralta", "BA Communication Arts", "1st Year", "19"]}
#Current school record

if option == 1: #Adding a student in the record
    new = input("Enter student no.: ")
    newname = input("Enter name: ")
    newdegree = input("Enter degree: ")
    newyear = input("Enter year level: ")
    newage = input("Enter age: ")

    record[new]=(newname, newdegree, newyear, newage) #adding a new key and list to the dictionary


    print("Student record has been added")

elif option == 2: #View a student's record
    student = input("Enter the Student no. of the student you want to view: ")
    print()
    for k in record: #checks each key in dictionary
        i = 0
        if student == k: #checks if user input student no. is equal to any key in the dictionary
            print("Student no:",student)
            for k in record[k]: #checks each element in the list per key
                if i == 0: #first element
                    print("Name:",k)
                if i == 1: #second element
                    print("Degree:",k)
                if i == 2: #third element
                    print("Year Level:",k)
                if i == 3: #fourth element
                    print("Age:",k)
                i = i + 1 #updates each item in list    



elif option == 3: #View all students
    for k in record: #Checks each key in dictionary
        student = k #each student is assigned to the key
        i = 0
        if student == str(k): #checks if student is in dictionary
            print("Student no:",student)
            for k in record[k]: #for every item in list per key
                if i == 0:
                    print("Name:",k)
                if i == 1:
                    print("Degree:",k)
                if i == 2:
                    print("Year Level:",k)
                if i == 3:
                    print("Age:",k)
                i = i + 1
            print()
    else:
        print("No Students on the record")



elif option == 4: #Deleting a student
    xstudent = input("Enter the student no. of the student you want to delete: ")
    print()
    for k in record: #Checks each key in dictionary
        if xstudent == str(k):#Checks if user input is in dictionary
            deleted = record.pop(k) #deletes the key and value
            print("Student record has been deleted.")
        else:
            print("Student is not part of the record. ")
        break



elif option == 5: #Deletes Record
    record.clear()
    print("All student records are now deleted")



elif option == 0: #Exit
    print("Thank you. Have a nice day!")

elif option ==6: 
    load()

elif option == 7: #Save
    save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that the variable 'i' is declared with the value 0, but isn't updated in your 'for' statements. 'i' needs to reference an object as you iterate through your records.

Comment: How should I address this problem? Will I declare the 'i' under the for loop?

Comment: Apologies, the 'i' does update correctly, I had mis-typed in my repl. The load function opens the file in read mode so you can't update it. Changing the 'r' to 'w' will open it in write mode, which should allow you to append your records.